# Too time consuming process

Tags: r

I am quite new to R and I need your help to figure it out a problem related to a very time consuming process.

I have a very large dataset that I am trying to subset to create file dat. The code I wrote is working but it takes to long and I don't know how to make it faster.

Here is the piece of code where I subset the dataset

```
df<-data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)

mylist <- list()

for(i in 1:(length(df$a))) {
  mylist[[i]] <- subset(df, a==df$a[i])   
  dep <- as.data.frame(mylist[i])
  SHYRMODY <- split(dep, data.frame(dep$a,dep$b, dep$c, dep$d), drop=TRUE)
  lapply(names(SHYRMODY),function(x, SHYRMODY)
    write.table(SHYRMODY[[x]],
                paste(x, ".dat", sep = ""),
                col.names=FALSE, 
                row.names=FALSE, 
                sep="\t",
                quote=FALSE),SHYRMODY)
}
```

Comment: Please describe in English what you are trying to do. I fear that attampting to optimize what is very likely incorrect logic will not do you any service.

Comment: Your code seems to be writing a very large number of files: those disk accesses could be slowing your code down.

Comment: No reason to create `dep` since it's only used in one line. Just write `data.frame(mylist[[i]][,1:4])` in your `split` call.

Comment: The biggest waste is your top `for` loops through every row when it should only loop through unique values of `a`. Also, you end up splitting your data twice via `subset` and `split` when you could just use one `split`, as I show in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
mylist    <- split(df, list(df$a, df$b, df$c, df$d), drop = TRUE)
filenames <- paste0(names(mylist), ".dat")

mapply(write.table, mylist, file = filenames,
      col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t", quote = FALSE)
```

The `drop = TRUE` option is so that it won't create empty files for combinations of `(a,b,c,d)` that have no data.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It is definitely more fast!! Using R I still need to forget for loop..